# Long Polling for more than 1 connection in same browser

Tags: node.js, comet, long-polling

I'm trying to implement long polling technique using NodeJS.

I have this basic code deployed on server.

```
http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log('onRequest reached');
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
console.log('Server has started.');
```

When requesting localhost:8080, onRequest is fired. When this connection is alive, I request the same page in second tab, but onRequest is not fired. However, requesting same page from another browser fires onRequest while first connection is still "long-polled".

Is there any limitation in browsers? How and why this happens? How can avoid this?

btw. I'm trying to implement long polling chat and notifications system. Actually requests should be made by AJAX call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the browser is waiting for a response. Try sending just the headers, immediately:

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    console.log('onRequest reached');
}
```

Another tip: If you're going to use long polling, I suggest you look into [Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/). There is pretty wide browser support for this, and there is also a [polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) for older browsers. Here is an [example in CoffeeScript](https://gist.github.com/1560654) showing how you can send events from a node.js server.

Comment: Sending headers immediately doesn't help.

Comment: Alright. Here's the thing: According to the HTTP/1.1 spec, a browser should only have maximum 2 connections open simultaneously to the same server. I'm not sure if your trouble comes from the first window requesting `/` and `/favicon.ico`, or something else... Anyway, it's a big drawback with long polling.

Comment: Oh. I have also read about 2 connections limit. But forgot about /favicon.ico :) Now I need way to avoid this. What does Facebook with his chat?

Comment: I'm guessing Facebook uses WebSockets, with fallbacks. If you want something more robust like that, you could look into the very popular [socket.io](http://socket.io/) module. It gives you WebSockets, long-polling, FlashSocket, iframe polling in a neat interface. I still think you should look into Server-Sent Events, though, since it's way simpler, with better browser support. Depends on the use case, though, as SSE is only server -> browser.

Comment: If you need a system that automatically shares and multiplexes the same connection on multiple tabs of the browser, check out Lightstreamer. To see alive demo of this behavior, go to the Chat launch page ( http://www.lightstreamer.com/demos#ChatDemo ) and click multiple times on "run the demo".